# How to get the url of the pkpass file from share button?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get specific information from the JSON in the pkpass file. The problem that I have is how to implement share functionality from wallet to my app and in general to register my app to work with PKPass.

For example, in the image, I want to have my app next to Mail and Message. [image]

I try to add com.apple.pkpass as DocumentType like this:

```
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>PKPass</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.apple.pkpass</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

After that, I understand that maybe I have to add it as imported UTI and I add this imported UTI:

```
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.composite-content</string>
                <string>com.apple.package</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>PKPass</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.pkpass</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>pkpass</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

And still, I can't share to my app. 
Maybe my question is: Is this possible? And if it is how to do it?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I made it with [App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/), adding these lines in the plist file of the extension.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
            $extensionItem.attachments,
            $attachment,
            (
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.apple.pkpass"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.apple.pkpass-data"
            )
            ).@count == 1
            ).@count == 1</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

After that, I just unzip the pkpass file with a library and read the JSON file.

I hope this can be useful for someone else.

Comment: Hi, one question when you unzipped the file you had to change the .pkpass to .zip ?

Comment: Hi, I'm using https://cocoapods.org/pods/Zip and I add this line  Zip.addCustomFileExtension("pkpass")